# How to set systemd hybrid-sleep instead of suspend to be used on idle?

Tags: suspend, systemd

I want to set the system to go to hybrid-sleep after some idle time.

I have an option in System Settings -> Power to suspend.

How can I change it to hybrid-sleep?

Comment: Probably commandline only :P

Comment: No. There is one way, but not a perfect one. I can change `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-hybrid-sleep.servece` to use `hybrid-sleep`. But there must be some way to change it in DE.

Comment: No there isn't. systemd and pm-utils conflict.

Comment: Why are you so sure? It is set somewhere either in source or in some config file.

Comment: Simple: if there was a method in the DE to change it it would be in power management and it is not. systemd seems to be made as a *replacement* for all services in Linux (So not just Unity) but the creators also did not bother with the different DE's.  Regarding "config file" unit files are kept in /etc/systemd/system  with a copy in /lib/systemd/system

Comment: Unity uses systemd services in xenial. It does not use pm. So they changed it somewhere. The question is where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an answer at Russian Ubuntu forums.

http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=282013.msg2221520#msg2221520

In `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` change

```
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
```

to

```
IdleAction=hybrid-sleep
IdleActionSec=1800
```

For some reason `30min` does not work. It works in seconds, that is OK.

Another option is to change the systemd.suspend service. It allows to use the GUI setting for idle timeout. But I do not recommend to use this one, since there is a perfect CLI solution.

I changed the systemd suspend service, but I do not think it is a perfect solution. But for a desktop without a UPS it may be a good option.

I changed a line in `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-suspend.service` from

```
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep suspend
```

to

```
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep hybrid-sleep
```